# fig.align and using pdf images not working in R Console

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I've been going back and forth between using RStudio and the R console (sending REPL commands from TextMate) to compile RMarkdown documents to a pdf.  When I use fig.align="center", it works fine in RStudio, but not in the console.  I've read about the need to put "graphics: yes" in the YAML and/or include the "graphics" or "graphicx" package, and I have tried all of these things, although it sounds like this issue was fixed sometime ago.  Also, the same .Rmd file results in a .md file that specifies using .png image files when run from the R console despite the fact that the default is supposed to be .pdf image files; but when run from RStudio the resulting .md file specifies using .pdf image files.  I'm not using any options when calling knit() from the console.  Any ideas why this might be happening when working in the console?

version

platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin13.4.0
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0
status
major          3
minor          3.1
year           2016
month          06
day            21
svn rev        70800
language       R
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair

Comment: On Ubuntu qith recent packages, this issue is not reproducible for me.

Comment: @J_F: Thanks for checking.  I've generated the default .Rmd script from RStudio for a .pdf document, and when I run it using the console it generates a intermediate .md file that specifies the use of a .png image file rather than a .pdf image file for the plot.  I've tried this on two different Macs and on one of them, under an older version of R (3.1.2) and an older version of knitr (1.9) and then upgraded to knitr 1.12.3, and it does the same thing in all cases.  Can anyone else verify whether this happens on other Mac, PCs, or unix/linux?

Comment: Note that R is now on version 3.3.1

Comment: @J_F:  Yes - that's what my main machine is running (listed in the session info in the original post).  It's a bit older laptop that I pulled out to also try the .Rmd script on via the console.